# Why am I getting "The requested configuration is currently not supported" while creating EC2 instance using Ansible playbook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using this Ansible playbook to create an EC2 instance.

```
  - name: Create EC2 instance with sg and tags
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
      - name: Creating EC2 instance
        ec2: 

          instance_type: t1.micro
          image: ami-0e01ce4ee18447327
          count: 1
          key_name: LampKey
          region: us-east-2
          wait: yes
          group: lamp
          instance_tags:
            Name: Test
            Env: Dev
```

While running this playbook, I get this error:

```
TASK [Creating EC2 instance] **************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Instance creation failed => Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations."}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Your AWS account may not be able to make t1.micro VMs.  Try something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t1.micro is an obsolete instance class, available only in some older AWS regions.  The us-east-2 region was never equipped with any t1.micro hardware.

If for some reason you still need to try to launch a t1.micro,  you may find capacity in some availability zones of us-east-1 or us-west-2, but the AMI would be different since those are regional.

Alternately, you might be able to launch this as t2.micro or t3.micro if the AMI is compatible with those classes.

Comment: I tried t2.micro and that worked like a charm. Thanks to both you and @Jack